# Set matplotlib tick locators, but specify spacing around them

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example if I have the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=11)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

Which looks as:

[image]

Here the range is set to include 0 and 11 so that there's some spacing around the plotted values, but the data only contains values of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` - so I'd like to *not* have `0` and `11` on the xaxis.

Looking at the documentation for `ticker.MultipleLocator` ([here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator)) it's not clear how this should be done (of if it can be with a locator). I tried to use the `view_limits` method but it just seems to return a tuple.

Ideally the values `0` and `11` would be gone, and the plot would look as:

[image]

## edit 1

The following "works"

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(left=1e-2, right=11 - 1e-2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

Though removing fractional amounts in order to not display something isn't a solution here as it's constrained to the base value of the `MultipleLocator`.

For example - what if I wanted the following:

```py
ax.set_xlim(left=1e-2, right=11 - 1e-2)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.5))
```

Which looks as:

[image]

Then I have `10.5` and so on, whereas I might still like the spacing to be a particular value not limited to the `MultipleLocator` size.

Comment: Maybe `ax.set_xlim(left=0.5, right=10.5)`? Or just leave out the call to `ax.set_xlim()` and let matplotlib set its default margins? It might help to first plot the data and only then modify ticks, limits etc.

Comment: or `ax.set_xlim(left=1e-2, right=11-1e-2)`? if you want that much space.  If you want more space `ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 11))` should work.

Comment: You can use `ax.set_xmargin()`, but it doesn't seem to play nicely with `ax.set_xlim()`. Maybe try setting the margins while letting matplotlib determine the max/min itself.

Comment: @JohanC I would like to be able to set the spacing though, rather than having to use <1 to get around a limitation.

Comment: @baileythegreen hrm, perhaps you could create an example? using `lim` seems natural as there is a fixed range for the data.

Comment: So - if there's _not_ any data which is of value `10` i still want that to be displayed

Comment: @JodyKlymak I've edited the post - but that's not generally useful as it's limited to having the spacing be the size of the `MultipleLocator` base value, whereas I'd like to be able to adjust it independently of that.

Comment: Then you are left with manually specifying the ticks, then you can make the margin whatever size you like.   You can also manually displace the spines https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/spines/spine_placement_demo.html. Finally, if you want this to be flexible, you can make your own custom Locator - they aren't that difficult.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I've never made a custom locator - if it's a simple solution you're familiar with it would be good to have an example :) I could iterate over the ticks and set those outside the desired range to be empty strings, but feel there are nicer approaches.

Comment: Unfortunately you don't have an objective criteria describing what you want, so its not easy to make a "nicer" approach.   I still recommend you manually specify the ticks (not just the labels)

Comment: @JodyKlymak yes, your point? A better approach could well be using a custom locator, which you've stated is easy. I've not done this, so it's not easy for me, if you're able to contribute that would be a good contribution to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the lower limit is something that is a bit tricky and not by default included in any of the Matplotlib ticker. However, taking a look at the source code
(https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L2734-L2751) gives a good hint how to implement this by deriving a new `MyMultipleLocator` class from `MultipleLocator` by yourself. Here is a piece of code that should work:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, _Edge_integer
import numpy as np

class MyMultipleLocator(MultipleLocator):
   def __init__(self, base=1.0, offset=0.):
      self._edge = _Edge_integer(base, 0)
      self._offset = offset

    def tick_values(self, vmin, vmax):
      # we HAVE to re-implement this method as it is called by 
      # xaxis.set_major_locator(...)
      vmin = self._edge.ge(vmin)
      step = self._edge.step
      n = (vmax - vmin + 0.001 * step) // step
      locs = self._offset + vmin - step + np.arange(n + 3) * step
      return self.raise_if_exceeds(locs)
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(1, 11)
ax.plot(x, np.random.randint(-3, 3, size=x.size))

tick_spacing = 2
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MyMultipleLocator(base=tick_spacing, offset=0))
```

You can now additionally change the offset manually in the last line. You could even do this automatically by checking if the minimum (the nearest int, that is) is an odd or an even number, but if I understand the question correctly then this is not required here.

Output from the above code:

[image]

## example 1

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MyMultipleLocator(base=1, offset=0))
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 10.5)
```

Which gives:

[image]

## example 2

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MyMultipleLocator(base=2, offset=0.5))
ax.set_xlim(0., 11)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work - i will have every other tick labelled then ? Including 0, which is specifically what i wanted to get rid of.

Comment: Thanks - I just ran your solution, using `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5));ax.set_xlim(left=0, right=11);ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MyMultipleLocator(base=1, offset=1))`  it doesn't match the expected output, i've updated the post to make this expected output clearer.

Comment: As far as I understand your new hints this should work if you set `offset=0`. In case it doesn't feel free to let me know what is mssing (Also, I fixed a small bug above).

Comment: i've added output - but this doesn't seem to work in the case of the spacing being `0.5` instead of `1`, if set to `0.5` it'll start at `1.5` (instead of `1`) and finish at `10`. I think it would be easier to understand / follow if you were able to reproduce the examples in the original post though. thanks

Comment: It's also not clear why `n + 3` is used in `np.arange` within the `locs` assignment

Comment: Umm... by adjusting base and offset I can essentially create all possible combinations of "starting value" for the xtick and difference between two ticks. Everything else is not the task of the ticker and should now be done using ax.set_xlim. Can you explain what "doesn't match the expected outcome"?

Comment: The output of the plot x-axis in your post  doesn't match the output of the axis in the original post. I had a brief look and I couldn't get it to work, if you're able to, for both cases given in the original post, that would be helpful to see.

Comment: Here are two examples how to use is: 1.
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MyMultipleLocator(base=1, offset=0));
ax.set_xlim(0.5, 10.5)`

2.:
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MyMultipleLocator(base=2, offset=0.5)); 
ax.set_xlim(0., 11)`

IMHO that should solve your problem, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243752/discussion-between-baxx-and-bandop).